# How to check all records of data extenion in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have an data extension that include +1000 records. But when i check for all records it shows only 200 records. At the button it is written that Only the top 200 records are displayed.

Is there anyway to check other records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! There is a way to check all.

Go to Contact Builder under Audience Builder. Then click on Data Extensions > click on data extension in which you want to check all records. At the bottom on left side it shows you no of item it shows per page, 25 by default. You can select upto 200 per page and on right side you can go though next - previous pages.

Comment: Thank you, I got it.